# Absurd SQLite Error in ICS

Tags: android, sqlite, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've implemented the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548533/full-android-database-helper-class-for-existing-sqlite-database) with the modifications from the [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178582/own-sqlite-database-and-onupgrade) also.

It all seems to work fine on the Android 2.2 emulator, however on an actual ICS device and also Jellybean emulator, I seem to be getting the following (strange) error:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 300300 to 12

There is no way my database version is 300300, and I have tried deleting and re-installing the application but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Any clue as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem not too long ago.  It seems to only happen on certain devices, that appear to have compiled the built-in SQLite library with write-ahead logging (WAL) turned on by default.

This results in a problem whenever you try to open a database in read-only mode, as databases that have WAL enabled cannot be opened in read-only mode.  The solution is to avoid using any SQLite API that tries to open the database in read-only mode, such as getReadableDatabase or the SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY flag.  Instead, try use getWritableDatabase, or the SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE flag whenever opening SQLite databases on Android.